# Cannot find namespace - ts(2503) [Exporting a namespace]

Tags: typescript, mongoose, javascript-namespaces

I am trying to export `mongoose.Types` in two different ways so that I can access it in another file to create **interfaces** or **types**. Why does 1 approach work and the other one doesn't? E.g

**❌ This doesn't work:**

`helper.ts`:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
export default { types: mongoose.Types }
```

`main.ts`

```
import helper from "./helper"
export interface Admin {
  userId: helper.types.ObjectId
}
```

& throws this error:  `Cannot find namespace 'helper'.ts(2503)`, while as this works perfectly:  ✅

`helper.ts`:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
export default mongoose.Types;
```

`main.ts`

```
import helper from "./helper"
export interface Admin {
  userId: helper.ObjectId
}
```

Incase you don't know, `mongoose.Types` is a namespace. Is there any particular way of handling import/export of namespaces. What exactly is happening here?

Comment: You're treating `mongoose.Types` as if it's a type when it's a `namespace`. Export types not namespaces.

Comment: Are namespaces `exportable`?

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make any sense. If you want to export types, export types, not the namespace.

Comment: May be I was not articulate enough in phrasing my problem. I just updated my question, kindly go through it once again & you'll understand what I am actually struggling with. Thanks.